# Create an array of Tuple depending on an array of data in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Suppose I have this data `int[] a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

I would like to create  `Tuple<int,int,bool>[]` where the first element is itself, the second is it's double value and the last element is whether it is an even number or not.

That is, the resulting data would be :

```
(1, 2, false)
(2, 4, true)
(3, 6, false)
(4, 8, true)
(5, 10, false)
```

One solution I have is to create a list, make a for loop over `a` array and `new` each `Tuple`, add to the list, and then finally use `.ToArray` on the list. But I think there must be an elegant way to do this. I don't mind using LINQ.

```
    int[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    List<Tuple<int,int,bool>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int, bool>>();
    {
        foreach(int i in a)
        {
            list.Add(new Tuple<int, int, bool>(i, i * 2, i % 2 == 0));
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
```

Comment: I suggest moving this question to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `Select` should do the trick:

```
var tuples  = a.Select(v => Tuple.Create(v, v * 2, v % 2 == 0)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a select query would solve the problem.

```
int[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result =  a.Select(x => Tuple.Create<int, int, bool>(x, 2 * x, x % 2 == 0)).ToArray();
```

Comment: oh .. he got it first :(

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto in my answer it's v, not x, and also v * 2 and not 2 * x. Don't be too hard on the guy, sometimes you don't get the updates in time...